# Create custom #warning flags

Tags: c++, objective-c, gcc, warnings, pragma

I'm building a commercial app, and we are using some GPL code to help us along.

How can I add `#warning` or `#error` statements so that when the code is built for debug, it warns, but when we build for release it throws errors?

I can do:

```
#warning this code is released under a CCL licensing scheme, see Source_Code_License.rtf
#warning this code is not LGPL-compliant
#warning this code was copied verbatim from a GP Licensed file
```

at the beginning of files, but can I do better?  Is there a better way of tagging a file if it's included?

I'm using Objective-C++ with gcc or clang.

Comment: If you're using Objective C, then why did you add a `c++` tag?

Comment: I'm using Objective-C++, some which is C++, some which is Objective-C and some is just combined and messy all over the place.

Comment: @Stephen; I apologize for messing this up. (You should properly @address comment replies, otherwise those you reply to won't see them on their Responses tab. I only found this accidentally.)

Comment: @sbi, I'm sorry.  I wasn't aware the @ actually worked.  I thought it was a twitter-thing.  Id should highlight itself or something.

Comment: @sbi, where can I go to tell people it should be highlighted?  meta?

Comment: @Stephen: _What_ should be "highlighted"?

Comment: @sbi, like the `@Stephen` portion of it.  Blue, or bolded, or something.  Just to know that it works on some level, feedback or something.

Comment: @Stephen: Ah, I see. Could be made a link, even. You could ask on meta. (If I were you, I'd first put some effort into finding the right tag for this and then searching whether this had been asked before.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use #pragma message instead.

Comment: Sure, here's an example: #warning This is a custom warning

Answer (score 5):

```
#ifdef SOME_SYMBOL
#error "foobar"
#else
#warning "foobar"
#endif
```

NDEBUG has a slightly different purpose (controlling assert) and may be #undef and re-defined selectively (reincluding assert.h to effect the change), so it probably wouldn't be the right symbol.  But it is a standard macro and could be used.

Note that #error is standard, but #warning is an extension.