# CMake and compiler warnings

Tags: gcc, cmake

I use `CMake` to generate unix makefiles. After that I compile project using `make` utility.
Problem is that I can't see any warnings! For example, this results in clean build without warnings:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    int first;
    int second;
public:
    Foo(int a, int b)
    : second(a) // invalid initialization order
    , first(b)
    {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int unused; // unused variable
    int x;
    double y = 3.14159;
    x = y; // invalid cast
    Foo foo(1,2);
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Unused variable and lossy variable cast - no warnings! My `CMakeLists.txt` file is minimalistic:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

When I run `cmake` and then `make` my output looks like this:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable main
[100%] Built target main
```

But when I add this line of code:

```
#warning ("Custom warning")
```

resulting output contains warning:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
../src/main.cpp:15:2: warning: #warning ("Custom Warning") [-Wcpp]
Linking CXX executable main
[100%] Built target main
```

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and GCC as a compiler. Maybe CMake passes some flag to compiler that results in absence of warnings. How can I check it? I can't read makefiles generated by CMake, they are a little bit cryptic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create custom #warning flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168245/create-custom-warning-flags)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The positions on compiler warnings are divided. There are package maintainers who will tell you that they know what they are doing, and compiler warnings should be ignored in any case. (I think they couldn't be more wrong.) But I guess that is why CMake mostly leaves the warning settings alone.

If you want to be a bit more sophisticated about it, check for the compiler being used, and add the flag to the specific property of the specific target.

### Apply to a Single Target

```
if ( CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC )
    target_compile_options(main PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra)
endif()
if ( MSVC )
    target_compile_options(main PRIVATE /W4)
endif()
```

### Apply to All Targets

```
if ( CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC )
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra")
endif()
if ( MSVC )
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4")
endif()
```

Note: add `-Werror` for GCC or `/WX` for MSVC to treat all warnings as errors. This will treat all warnings as errors. This can be handy for new projects to enforce warning strictness.

Also, `-Wall -Wextra` does not mean "all errors"; historically `-Wall` meant "all errors *that everybody could agree on*", and `-Wextra` "some more". Start with that, then peruse the manual for *your* version of GCC, and find what *else* the compiler can do for you with regards to warnings...

Comment: @NormanBLancaster: Thank you for your suggested edit, but I don't really believe in `-Werror` (different compiler versions toss different warnings, and turning them into errors by default makes the build fragile). Repeating the conditional in `endif()` makes the code harder to read IMHO. And overwriting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` isn't a good habit either... On the upside, I added `-Wextra`, so... ;-)

Comment: I believe it's `target_compile_options`, not `target_compile_option`.

Comment: Is the argument to `endif` really required?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: It was for a previous version of CMake. It is no longer, and I do not use it anymore. Edited.

Comment: @DevSolar Ah, okay. Good to know! (You missed the first `endif` in the second code block)

Comment: A modern way is to use [`add_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html#example)

Comment: The quotes around "-Wall -Wextra" are not correct, because this would make CMake generate a _single_ option '-Wall -Wextra' instead of two options '-Wall' '-Wextra'. Just write `target_compile_options(main PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra)` (tested with CMake 3.20.2)

Comment: @UniversE: Does this make any practical difference?

Comment: @DevSolar yes, it does not work :-D Try `gcc '-Wall -Wextra' test.c` instead of `gcc -Wall -Wextra test.c` and observe gcc complaining with `unrecognized command line option ‘-Wall -Wextra’;`

Comment: You should not use `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, flags are different per compiler and may change in the future.
Some great explanations from Daniel Pfeifer
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk&t=1237s

Comment: @Jorge At the time of writing this answer, that was the only way to do it. Feel free to suggest and edit to adapt to newer procedures.

Answer (score -2):

Solve problem with this line of code:

```
add_definitions ("-Wall")
```

Result now looks like this:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
../src/main.cpp:15:2: warning: #warning ("Custom warning") [-Wcpp]
../src/main.cpp: In constructor ‘WarnSrc::WarnSrc(int, int)’:
../src/main.cpp:6:9: warning: ‘WarnSrc::second’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
../src/main.cpp:5:9: warning:   ‘int WarnSrc::first’ [-Wreorder]
../src/main.cpp:8:5: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
../src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../src/main.cpp:19:9: warning: unused variable ‘unused’ [-Wunused-variable]
../src/main.cpp:20:9: warning: variable ‘x’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
Linking CXX executable main
[100%] Built target main
```

Comment: Strange that it's not enabled by default.

Comment: This is a bad idea! `add_definitions` is passed in contexts that do not expect `-W` options, e.g. MinGW's windres, which will promptly break. Probably others too.

Comment: Although this might not be ideal, this answer was helpful, and for that reason i think it deserved a thumbs up. The point of stack overflow, is to provide answers, and the more different approaches and answers tehre are to a problem, the better, as long as people are aware of the pros and cons.

Comment: In the cmake 3.0.2 documentation which is still online https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_definitions.html, add_definitions is described and there is no language like that in the 3.1.3 documentation that says that it "should" be restricted to your -D options. In the 3.23.0 documentation it specifically says that other commands should be used because there are 3 other commands that are recommended. I have a bit of code that uses cmake 2.8 so we use include_directories() and add_definitions() and that's it. The smart move is to follow this answer and its comments if your cmake is old.