# qcc - CMake and compiler warnings

Tags: c++, cmake, qcc

I have been using cmake for a QNX 6.5 build which uses a qcc compiler. When I run make to build the project it does not show any errors (original project without the cmake did).  This [form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231292/cmake-and-compiler-warnings) was almost what I needed, but not quite. I tried to add the code below to my QNX_Toochian.cmake, but nothing happens.  I suspect that it is because the qcc compiler needs a different flag then -Wall.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
```

I also found this [website](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.0/neutrino/utilities/q/qcc.html) which talks about setting the warning levels, but I still don't understand how to format this for my QNX_Toolchain.cmake.

One other resource that I found that does configure a QNX_Toochain.cmake is [here](https://github.com/preet/scratch/wiki/OpenSceneGraph-on-the-Playbook). They also are setting flags for there build, but I don't know how to simply what they have done.

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -lang-c++ -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-all -Wno-psabi -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT" CACHE STRING "Playbook QCC C++ Flags" FORCE)
```

So if anyone has an idea of how to get a QNX qcc cmake project to display errors that is what I am looking for.